# How to alias 'disass <something>' to a disassembly at the current location?

Tags: gdb, disassembly

I'm having trouble getting a disassembly at my current location. GDB does not recognize `.` (dot) as "here":

```
(gdb) disass .
A syntax error in expression, near `.'.
```

Issuing `disass $pc` disassembles from the start of the function and not "here":

```
(gdb) disass $pc
Dump of assembler code for function _ZN8CryptoPP6RDSEED13GenerateBlockEPhm:
   0x000000000056b962 <+0>:     push   %r13
   0x000000000056b964 <+2>:     push   %r12
   0x000000000056b966 <+4>:     push   %rbp
...

<skip 5 pages of output>

   0x000000000056ba88 <+294>:   mov    %rdi,0x8(%rsp)
=> 0x000000000056ba8d <+299>:   test   %edx,%edx
   0x000000000056ba8f <+301>:   je     0x56ba7f <_ZN8CryptoPP6RDSEED13GenerateBlockEPhm+285>
...
```

How do I create an alias or a rule to provide a disassembly at the current location, some number of instructions before the current location, and some number of instructions before the current location?

It seems like this should be built-in functionality, but GDB does not appear to offer it. Other low level debuggers, like WinDbg, has the built-in functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`disas` disassembles the entire function (as designed and documented).

You are looking for `x/10i $pc` (replace 10 with desired number of instructions).

> How can I alias disass . to the command above?

There is GDB `alias` command, but it rejects my attempts to use it:

```
(gdb) alias ds = x/10i $pc
Invalid command to alias to: x/10i $pc
```

User-defined command works:

```
(gdb) define disas
Type commands for definition of "disas".
End with a line saying just "end".
>x/10i $pc
>end
```

Comment: Thanks Employed Russian. How can I alias `disass .` to the command above? I don't want to perform the extra typing or try to remember the extra commands.